# Apply resizable only width more than 1024px

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have resizable function in my page:

```
$(function() {
$( "#droppable" ).droppable({
  create: function( event, ui ) {$( this ).hide(0)}
});
$( "#droppable" ).on( "dropover", function( event, ui ) {  $( this )
         $( this ).text('¿Eliminar?')} );
    $( ".panel" ).draggable();
 $( "#droppable" ).droppable({
      activeClass: "ui-state-default",
      hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
      drop: function( event, ui ) {
        $(ui.draggable).toggle( "scale" );
        $( this ).show(0).delay(700).toggle( "clip" );
        $( this ).addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )
        .text('¡Eliminado!')    
         }
    });
$( "#droppable" ).on( "dropout", function( event, ui ) {  $( this )
         $( this ).text('Arrastrar y soltar para eliminar')} );
    $( ".panel" ).resizable({
      minHeight: 119,
      minWidth: 352,
      maxHeight: 219,
      maxWidth: 452
    });
  });
```

But i want to apply it only when the resolution is more than 1024. I applied it but this doesn't work, it's throws me ) token error:

FULL ERROR: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )

```
    $(function() {
$( "#droppable" ).droppable({
  create: function( event, ui ) {$( this ).hide(0)}
});
$( "#droppable" ).on( "dropover", function( event, ui ) {  $( this )
         $( this ).text('¿Eliminar?')} );
    $( ".panel" ).draggable();
 $( "#droppable" ).droppable({
      activeClass: "ui-state-default",
      hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
      drop: function( event, ui ) {
        $(ui.draggable).toggle( "scale" );
        $( this ).show(0).delay(700).toggle( "clip" );
        $( this ).addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )
        .text('¡Eliminado!')    
         }
    });
$( "#droppable" ).on( "dropout", function( event, ui ) {  $( this )
         $( this ).text('Arrastrar y soltar para eliminar')} );
if ($(window).width() > 1024) {
    $( ".panel" ).resizable({
      minHeight: 119,
      minWidth: 352,
      maxHeight: 219,
      maxWidth: 452
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Could you paste in the full error?

Comment: I'm seeing two }); enclosing shouldnt that be one?

Comment: Yes because i forget to write the complete function, check it now

Comment: Aboca is correct. there should only be 1 }); http://jsfiddle.net/5QHav/22/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There you go, you had syntax errors, $(function(){ => (function(){, some $(this) inside the nested functions made errors too, and the last }); was done before closing the if }

```
(function() {
$( "#droppable" ).droppable({
  create: function( event, ui ){
      $(this).hide(0);
  }
});

$( "#droppable" ).on( "dropover", function( event, ui ) {
         $( this ).text('¿Eliminar?');
});

$( ".panel" ).draggable();

 $( "#droppable" ).droppable({
      activeClass: "ui-state-default",
      hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
      drop: function( event, ui ) {
        $(ui.draggable).toggle( "scale" );
        $(this).show(0).delay(700).toggle( "clip" );
        $(this).addClass("ui-state-highlight").text('¡Eliminado!'); 
       }
    });

$("#droppable").on( "dropout", function( event, ui ) { 
         $(this).text('Arrastrar y soltar para eliminar');
});

if ($(window).width() > 1024) {
    $( ".panel" ).resizable({
      minHeight: 119,
      minWidth: 352,
      maxHeight: 219,
      maxWidth: 452
    });
  }
});
```